# Why are the count of Substrings starting at an index equal to the size of the substring? What is the math behind this?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

For example, lets consider a string "abcabc".

If we want to count the number of substrings starting at the first 'a',the I will have the following substrings,

a

ab

abc

abca

abcab

abcabc

count = 6

But we don't need to enumerate all substrings and count.

The count is the size of substring starting at the index and till where we would like to check.

So here we are starting at the first index and we are looking for all substrings starting at the first index, so the rest of the string ie 6.

But my question is what is the intuition behind this?
What is the math concept behind this type of counting and why is this correct and what are the assumptions to make this argument?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  "*What is the intuition behind this?*"  That's how length works...  Each substring can be defined based on starting position and ending position... It seems perfectly intuitive and obvious to me and I would not feel compelled to try to explain it.

Comment: For what its worth, you may want to consider the empty string to be a substring as well depending on your specific contexts and needs.